# Oracle sub query along with Case statement In causing single-row subquery returns more than one row error

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a Scenario to use the Below sql in oracle which uses a Case statement along with a Sub Query, I get the following error message when trying to execute it .

The error I get :

ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 - "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
                P.AGNT_NO,
                P.AGENCY_NO,
                AP.AGRMNT_ID,
                P.SRC_CD,
                PR.PARTY_ROLE_NM,
                APR.AGNT_PARTCPTN_FCTR_NO
            FROM
                EODS.PARTY_EV P
                INNER JOIN EODS.AGRMNT_PARTY_EV AP ON P.PARTY_ID = AP.PARTY_ID
                INNER JOIN EODS.AGRMNT_PARTY_ROLE_EV APR ON AP.AGRMNT_PARTY_ID = APR.AGRMNT_PARTY_ID
                INNER JOIN EODS_REF.REF_PARTY_ROLE_RV PR ON APR.PARTY_ROLE_ID = PR.SRC_ROLE_ID
                AND PR.PARTY_ROLE_NM IN ('SERVICING AGENT','WRITING AGENT')
                INNER JOIN EODS.CVRG C ON AP.AGRMNT_ID = C.AGRMNT_ID
                INNER JOIN EODS_REF.REF_PROD_RV RP ON C.PROD_ID = RP.SRC_PROD_ID
            WHERE
                PR.PARTY_ROLE_NM =
                    CASE
                        WHEN P.SRC_CD = 'PRD4' THEN 'SERVICING AGENT'
                        WHEN (P.SRC_CD = 'ELS' AND RP.PLAN_CD = 'FMYMVAY0') THEN 'SERVICING AGENT'
                        WHEN (P.SRC_CD = 'ELS' AND RP.PLAN_CD = 'INSELDZ0') THEN 'SERVICING AGENT'
                        WHEN (P.SRC_CD = 'ELS' AND RP.PLAN_CD = 'SENSELZ0') THEN 'SERVICING AGENT'
                        WHEN (P.SRC_CD IN ('CLIC','PRD5')) THEN (SELECT
                                PARTY_ROLE_NM
                            FROM
                                (
                                    SELECT
                                        RNK,
                                        PARTY_ROLE_NM
                                    FROM
                                        (
                                            SELECT
                                                P.AGNT_NO,
                                                P.AGENCY_NO,
                                                AP.AGRMNT_ID,
                                                P.SRC_CD,
                                                RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY
                                                    AP.AGRMNT_ID
                                                    ORDER BY
                                                        PR.PARTY_ROLE_NM
                                                    DESC
                                                ) RNK,
                                                PR.PARTY_ROLE_NM,
                                                APR.AGNT_PARTCPTN_FCTR_NO
                                            FROM
                                                EODS.PARTY_EV P
                                                INNER JOIN EODS.AGRMNT_PARTY_EV AP ON P.PARTY_ID = AP.PARTY_ID
                                                INNER JOIN EODS.AGRMNT_PARTY_ROLE_EV APR ON AP.AGRMNT_PARTY_ID = APR.AGRMNT_PARTY_ID
                                                INNER JOIN EODS_REF.REF_PARTY_ROLE_RV PR ON APR.PARTY_ROLE_ID = PR.SRC_ROLE_ID
                                            WHERE
                                                PR.PARTY_ROLE_NM IN ('SERVICING AGENT','WRITING AGENT')
                                        )
                                    WHERE
                                        RNK = 1
                                )
                        )
                        ELSE 'WRITING AGENT'
                    END
```

Comment: What result you are getting when running your sub-query alone.

Comment: Your sub-query should not return more than one row, as you are comparing it to a single value.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai when I Execute the subquery alone I get the out put Values for both SERVICING AGENT','WRITING AGENT'

Comment: @gsalem Is there an alternative way to write the query to fix the issue ?

Comment: As @mt0 noted in his answer, you can use an aggregate function to get just one row, e.g. max(PARTY_ROLE_NM). But it can also point to some missing predicates in the sub-query.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for some sample data and the expected output for that sample data. You probably have an XY-problem and there is a much simpler solution but unless you explain the problem and give us some data to test against we are not going to find it and are mostly going to be guessing at the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `RANK` analytic function can return multiple rows ranked 1st within each partition if there are multiple rows which would be ordered identically by the `ORDER BY` clause.

   If this is the cause then you could consider changing from `RANK` to `ROW_NUMBER` which will only ever have a single row numbers 1st within each partition.
2. If you have multiple partitions in the `RANK`ing then there will be rows ranked first in each of those partitions and the `CASE` expression is expecting a single row to be returned from the sub-query.

   To fix it, you could aggregate:

   ```sql
   WHEN (P.SRC_CD IN ('CLIC','PRD5')) THEN (
     SELECT LISTAGG(PARTY_ROLE_NM, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY party_role_nm)
     FROM   (
       SELECT P.AGNT_NO,
              P.AGENCY_NO,
              AP.AGRMNT_ID,
              P.SRC_CD,
              RANK() OVER (                     -- or ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY AP.AGRMNT_ID
                ORDER BY PR.PARTY_ROLE_NM DESC
              ) AS RNK,
              PR.PARTY_ROLE_NM,
              APR.AGNT_PARTCPTN_FCTR_NO
       FROM   EODS.PARTY_EV P
              INNER JOIN EODS.AGRMNT_PARTY_EV AP
              ON P.PARTY_ID = AP.PARTY_ID
              INNER JOIN EODS.AGRMNT_PARTY_ROLE_EV APR
              ON AP.AGRMNT_PARTY_ID = APR.AGRMNT_PARTY_ID
              INNER JOIN EODS_REF.REF_PARTY_ROLE_RV PR
              ON APR.PARTY_ROLE_ID = PR.SRC_ROLE_ID
       WHERE  PR.PARTY_ROLE_NM IN ('SERVICING AGENT','WRITING AGENT')
     )
     WHERE  RNK = 1
   )
   ```
3. You may have forgotten to correlate the outer query with the sub-query:

   ```sql
   WHEN (P.SRC_CD IN ('CLIC','PRD5')) THEN (
     SELECT LISTAGG(PARTY_ROLE_NM, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY party_role_nm)
     FROM   (
       SELECT P.AGNT_NO,
              P.AGENCY_NO,
              AP.AGRMNT_ID,
              P.SRC_CD,
              RANK() OVER (                     -- or ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY AP.AGRMNT_ID
                ORDER BY PR.PARTY_ROLE_NM DESC
              ) AS RNK,
              PR.PARTY_ROLE_NM,
              APR.AGNT_PARTCPTN_FCTR_NO
       FROM   EODS.PARTY_EV P
              INNER JOIN EODS.AGRMNT_PARTY_EV AP
              ON P.PARTY_ID = AP.PARTY_ID
              INNER JOIN EODS.AGRMNT_PARTY_ROLE_EV APR
              ON AP.AGRMNT_PARTY_ID = APR.AGRMNT_PARTY_ID
              INNER JOIN EODS_REF.REF_PARTY_ROLE_RV PR
              ON APR.PARTY_ROLE_ID = PR.SRC_ROLE_ID
       WHERE  PR.PARTY_ROLE_NM IN ('SERVICING AGENT','WRITING AGENT')
     ) x
     WHERE  x.RNK       = 1
     AND    x.agnt_no   = p.agnt_no
     AND    x.agency_no = p.agency_no
     AND    x.agrmnt_id = ap.agrmnt_id
     AND    x.src_id    = p.src_id
   )
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In the sub query

```
SELECT
                                        RNK,
                                        PARTY_ROLE_NM
                                    FROM
                                        (
                                            SELECT
                                                P.AGNT_NO,
                                                P.AGENCY_NO,
                                                AP.AGRMNT_ID,
                                                P.SRC_CD,
                                                RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY
```

put count(*) to see if there any duplicates

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).